# ¿como crear un archivo jsp?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en java y me toca aprender sobre java web en netbeans 17 cree mi proyecto en maven usando tomcat 10 hasta ahi todo bien al momento de crear un archovo jsp en la carpeta web pages crea un archivo totalmente vacio y me dice que el archo ya existe por lo cual no me deja avanzar por mas que le cambie el nombre sigue realizando el mismo procedimiento de crear un archivo vacio y arrojar el mensaje de que el archivo ya existe no si si a alguien mas le haya pasado

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.